Dart build_runner not building
I'm getting error when I running dart run build_runner build command also with --delete-conflicting-outputs.
I can't remember which actions I doing before that error. But I don't added new packages and before it works fine.
The error if following:
PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 
'.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.dill.cached' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55)
#1      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:381)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _FileStreamConsumer.addStream.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:205)
<asynchronous suspension>

Flutter version 3.19.5

No issues found!

by flutter doctor

Try deleting build folder and then run it again.
